# I've got a jQuery autocomplete JSON Parse error even when using a local array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery autocomplete function on a Wordpress site. Eventually I want to hook the input field up to an ajax call that will request the data from the data base. However I'm stuck with a weird error even when trying to use a local array as the source. Here's the javascript code.

```
$(".registration#billing_company").autocomplete({
    source: ["Result1", "Result2"]
})
```

And here's the error that get's received when trying to use the attached input field.

SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

I'd understand if this was an ajax call that was responding with some weird string but it's literally just an array. And help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which library/plugin are you using for autocomplete?  (edit: looks like jquery-ui)

Comment: check the endpoint youre calling exists and returns json and youre not getting a 404 response (which would be a html page with < character first).

Comment: @freedomn-m There's a live-search.js file that is included with the theme that is the default. It is still the jQuery UI autocomplete under the hood though - I've checked the source. I tried deregistering that and using a different cdn https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.4.11/jquery.autocomplete.js and still had no success

Comment: What does the network tab say? Is there a request that returns html?

Comment: @Andreas It's returning the page itself - the page the input field is on.

Comment: Then inspect the source of that request and "fix" it

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
Turns out it was the library I was using. Downloaded the jQuery-ui library from the offical site and that worked fine...